# How to use saddle point approximation for integrands with $e^{ix}$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, approximation, complex-integration

I have an integral to evaluate

$I = \int_m^{\infty} \sqrt{x^2-m^2} \;e^{-ixb} dx$

where m and b is constant with b is very large as per the requirement for saddle point approximation. In saddle point method if we given the integral of the form

$I = \int_a^b g(x) \;e^{f(x)\,t} dx$

where t is a constant and very large, the soluation is

$I \approx g(x_0) \,e^{f(x_0)\,t}\int_a^b  \;e^{\frac{f''(x_0)\,t\,(x-x_0)^2}{2} } dx$

we expanded the function $f(x)$ about its maxima. $x_0$ is the point where $f(x)$ is maximum.

In this problem $f(x) = -ix$ and $ g(x)= \sqrt{x^2-m^2} $. How do I use saddle point method here? Because when $x=m \;,f(x)$ is maximum and then $g(x_0)=0$. If I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: The integral doesn’t converge; $\sqrt{x^2-m^2}$ grows like $x$ while $e^{-ixb}$ oscillates with constant frequency as $x\to\infty$. If you had something like $e^{-(ix+x^2)}$ you might be able to do something, since the decay of $e^{-x^2}$ beats the growth of $\sqrt{x^2-m^2}$.

Comment: In problems like these, you deform the contour so that the complex exponential has a maximum along the contour, then you get a Laplace-type integral again. (There is also the residual question of whether the original thing even converges which it seems like it probably doesn't).